# Is there a way to determine whether a facebook url leads to a profile or a page through facebook php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

The users of my website can add facebook fanpages and profiles to the website. I am trying to figure out a way, to determine whether a url that was added leads to a facebook profile or to a facebook fanpage.
I have the facebook php-sdk version 5 installed on the website and I also have valid access tokens for my own profile.

Is there a way to find out whether any given facebook url leads to a profile or a fanpage without having and access token to either of them?

Comment: There is no API that takes a URL and tells you what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to find out whether any given facebook url leads to a profile or a fanpage without having and access token to either of them?

No official one.

You can still try and make an educated guess, if you got a profile URL that contains a username (user or page).

Trying to access a user profile that you have no access to this way, currently still results in the error message, *“(#803) Cannot query users by their username (xyz).”* Facebook introduced this error message after they removed the `username` field from the user object.

If it is a page instead, and again you have no token that specifically grants access, then you should get the error *“(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. […]”* (assuming that your app doesn’t have this feature reviewed & approved; if it had, you should be able to read basic public page data using this request, so you could draw your conclusions from that.)

That would be for pages that are currently public and have no access restrictions; if that wasn’t the case, you should get the message, *“(#10) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing reviewable feature 'Page Public Content Access', or does not support this operation. […]”*

But there might also be other situations. Not every user has a username set for their personal profile - and if you got a numeric user id only, you’d get *“Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'xyz' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.”* But that message is not specific to user profiles, you might get it regarding other objects you simply do not have access to as well.

And on top of that, Facebook might probably changes this, if they feel that this exposes more information than they are comfortable with. They might switch to a more generic error message covering all those cases at some point, or something like that.

Unless you absolutely *have to* make sure that your app knows what’s a user profile and what’s a page, I would recommend against trying this - and rather trust your users that they will pay a bit of intention, if the result matters to them.

---

Edit: One more thing that could be - partially - used, is the syntax to get information about “external” Open Graph objects, by specifying the URLs using the `?ids=…` syntax. A request for `?ids=https://www.facebook.com/zuck,https://www.facebook.com/facebook` currently yields the following result,

```
{
  "https://www.facebook.com/facebook": {
    "name": "Facebook",
    "id": "20531316728"
  },
  "https://www.facebook.com/zuck": {
    "id": "https://www.facebook.com/zuck"
  }
}
```

As you can see, for the first one, which is the official page for Facebook, it returns the page ID, whereas for the second one, which is Mark’s personal profile, it doesn’t. But, careful - for non-public pages, you would not get any ID here either. But maybe in combination with the aforementioned requests, that will result in different error messages depending on the type of object, that could increase the quality of the “educated guess” here.